# How can I increase my screen resolution?

Tags: 11.10, graphics, resolution

As title states, I would like to know if it's possible for my graphic card to have higher resolution than 1024x768 which shows as maximum resolution in Display setting. My screen is [32 inch Polaroid HDTV](http://reviews.cnet.com/flat-panel-tvs/polaroid-flm-3232/1707-6482_7-31975694.html).

My graphic card information:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:cfe80000-cfefffff ioport:c800(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:cfe40000-cfe7ffff
```

I have Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks in advance.

As [Intel](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intel915g/sb/CS-012579.htm) Website states:

```
256-bit graphics core
8/16/32 bpp
Up to 8.5 GB/sec memory bandwidth with DDR2 533 MHz
1.3 GP/sec and 1.3 GT/sec fill rate
128 MB maximum video memory
2048x1536 at 85 Hz maximum resolution
Dynamic Display Modes for flat-panel and wide-screen support
Operating systems supported: Microsoft Windows XP*, Windows 2000*, Linux*-compatible (Xfree86 source available)
```

[XRandr](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) shows me modes below, but few weeks earlier this way caused me to to use safe mode because the higher resolution did not work right and I was left with blank screen.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TVs native resolution is 1366x768, so you won't be able to go much above 1024x768.

Is 1366x768 what you are hoping to achieve?

--Edit 1--

Looks like lots of people have trouble with HDTVs not reporting the resolutions they support. What do you have in your `/etc/x11/xorg.conf`?

--Edit 2--

Have you tried this? - [Adding undetected resolutions to xorg](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

If you are interested, you can view the info your monitor reports about itself by installing and running read-edid

`sudo apt-get install read-edid`
`sudo get-edid | parse-edid`

Comment: So it's up to the screen what's the max resolution I can get?

Comment: Yes-ish, unless you want to scroll to see the entire screen, it usually the lesser of your screen's max resolution and your graphics card's max resolution.

Comment: What does this do in your last edit? I get output saying: The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
parse-edid: IO error reading EDID

Comment: EDID is the Extended Display Identification Data. Basically, your monitors response to "What do you support?" HDTVs are known for having lackluster EDID and based on your comment, your HDTV is no different. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Well, can't do much more than using 1366x768 resolution. I guess your answer is worth accepting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just like to mention that these few lines of code fix my problem and change the resolution to 1368x768.

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```